# How do I protect a commercial app built with Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'd like to know how to protect a commercial app built with [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/).

I'm not talking about the source code. At least for my specific scenario, I believe the minified bundle generated by Webpack is secure enough (except for the security part). I'm talking about preventing non-paying users to actually access the application.

**Here's what I thought of:**

In the website, the user can generate an activation code. The activation code is simply the Base64 of the user's e-mail address plus a digital signature. The app contains the signature public key so it can verify the activation code. This seems secure enough for me except that someone can hack the bundle to start returning true every time. I can't think of a way to bypass this.

**So, is there a better way to protect a commercial app built with Electron?**

If I don't find a better way, I'm probably going with what I described and live with the risk.

Comment: Discussion on electron about source code protection, which may give some further insight on the topic: https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/3041

Answer (score 15):

I believe this topic has nothing to do with the app being built with electron as almost all apps can be reverse-engineered. It's only easier for apps built with javascript but still it's always possible with other apps.

What you might want to do is make some of the functionality depend on some parts not included in the app code. Like a feature not bundled with the app but rather has to be downloaded from a server upon activation. This would be a good advantage for having a js app as it's easier to inject new scripts.

Comment: That's a good advice +1. It's still abstract to me how to make something my app depends upon and that's not included, in such a way that it would be difficult to crack by just copying and pasting. But I'm thinking of living with the risk using the approach I described. For every release someone would have to crack the bundle to stop looking at the signed activation code, which I'm starting to think is too much of a hassle for an app that is going to cost $15. Thank you!

Comment: Solid idea. I can query the server and check if a user has a key to receive the data.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the JS library "bytenode". This library and it's command line allows you to convert your JS files into V8 bytecode binary files.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytenode
https://github.com/OsamaAbbas/bytenode

Here is how it works:

1.you install bytenode 1/locally and 2/globally.

```
npm i bytenode -g && npm i bytenode
```

2.you convert (compile) your JS into JSC binary file using the global bytenode command line.

```
bytenode -c test.js
```

3.you must call the local bytenode module thanks to require and then you call your .jsc binary files in which you have your JS file:

```
const bytenode = require('bytenode');
bytenode.runBytecodeFile('/path/to/test.jsc');
```

Comment: Well ... it seems not true anymore... : https://swarm.ptsecurity.com/how-we-bypassed-bytenode-and-decompiled-node-js-bytecode-in-ghidra/